# Getting json object into jsf view page

Tags: jquery, json, jsf

Hi I have to used  `json` to put the list or any data into key value pair for this i used `json` object .Now please tell me the way of retrieving that `json` object into `jsf` view page .I am not able to figure out how to get the json object which contains data in key value pair into the jsf view page
here is my code of

jsf BeanManager

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
class DiaryManager{
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    public void setView(){
       jsonObject=new  JSONObject();
       jsonObject.put("aptId", diaryViewBean.getApptid());
       jsonObject.put("sessionID", diaryViewBean.getSessionid());
       jsonObject.put("startdate", diaryViewBean.getStartDateBlock());
       jsonObject.put("event", eventobj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why in the first place you want to mess with JSON if you chose JSF? But if you insist, you can deal with ajax response the usual JavaScript way.

Comment: To which component you want that jason object to render?

Comment: Also, be sure to carefully read BalusC's answer to [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/1820286) to gain understanding on how to deal with JSON objects.